# How to use `gsettings set` to configure GNOME shell extension called Arc Menu?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gsettings, arc-menu

I would like to change the icon image of the arc-menu found in *GNOME Tweak Tool* > *Extensions* > *Arc menu* > *Appearance* > *Customize menu button appearance* > *Button appearance*.

However, I want to use the `gsettings set` command to achieve this, or any other equivalent cmdline commands to do so. Strange thing is that it is not visible in the Dconf Editor, i.e. `/org/gnome/shell/extensions`. Yet the Arc-menu is visible, it appears in both  https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and *GNOME Tweak Tool* > *Extensions*. What must I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens is when you install this extension..

the directory `arc-menu@linxgem33.com` is installed here `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/arc-menu@linxgem33.com`

If you list the contents..

```
ls .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/arc-menu@linxgem33.com/schemas/
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ ls .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/arc-menu@linxgem33.com/schemas/
gschemas.compiled  org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu.gschema.xml
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

the gschema.xml file is here.. you need to copy this to `$HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

Note: check the directory `glib-2.0/schemas` is already available under `$HOME/.local/share/` or not. If not create the directory first.

```
cp .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/arc-menu@linxgem33.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu.gschema.xml .local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

and then compile

```
glib-compile-schemas $HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

Once it is successfully compiled with the above command..

now you can use `gsettings` or `dconf`

[image]

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu custom-menu-button-icon
'/home/pratap/1.png'
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu menu-button-icon
'Custom_Icon'
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

---

Please note that when ever you remove the Arc-Menu Extension via Ubuntu Software

remove the schemas file for this Arc-Menu `$HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu.gschema.xml`

```
rm $HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.arc-menu.gschema.xml
```

and compile..

`glib-compile-schemas $HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. They worked. :) However, I encountered another [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1143/logout-button/) which did not contain a schemas directory for a user to download the schema file to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`. What should I do in such a circumstance? Why isn't there a standard directory and file layout for a GNOME shell extensions?

Comment: I will post a separate question for this other extension.

Comment: New question is [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1172234/541417)