# How to use `gsettings set` to configure GNOME shell extension called `Log Out Button`?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dconf, gsettings

I am not able to use `gsettings set` to configure the GNOME shell extension called `Log Out Button`. I had downloaded the extension's zip file from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1143/logout-button/). Thereafter, I extracted its directories and files to either `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/LogOutButton@kyle.aims.ac.za` or `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/LogOutButton@kyle.aims.ac.za`, enabled it, and the did <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> followed by <kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to restart the GNOME shell.

The extension works, but it did not appear in the `Dconf Editor`, nor could I use `gsetting set` to make any changes to the extension. According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171112/541417), there should be a `org.gnome.shell.extensions.LogOutButton.gschema.xml` file in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/LogOutButton@kyle.aims.ac.za/schema` that has to be downloaded to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` for compilation. However, the file `org.gnome.shell.extensions.LogOutButton.gschema.xml` does not exist.

What should I do in such a circumstance? Why isn't there a standard directory and file layout for installing GNOME shell extensions?

Comment: Hi, it is the interest of the developer.. since this is just a button and does not require any further settings other than enable the extension or disable the extension.. what are your thoughts to have command line settings for this extension? do you have any other than enabling and disabling?

Comment: @PRATAP I am new to GNOME. Base on your comment, I am beginning to understand the rationale for the differences between extensions like `LogOutButton` and `arc-menu`. Yes, I would like the `LogOutButton` to have a KEY to allow users to determine it's location, e.g. to be the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or ... button from the right. A wish-list.  ;)

Comment: Oh, Ok.. in that case.. you can request the programmer/ creator of this extension to have such a Option which is possible for the programmers..