# How to refresh Dconf Editor in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

After removing unwanted GNOME shell extensions xxxxx from:

- `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
- `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

and removing it's schemas from `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` with cmds like so:

```
$ sudo rm org.gnome.shell.extensions.xxxxx.gschema.xml
```

and recompiling `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, I noticed that `Dconf Editor` sometimes still shows the removed GNOME shell extensions.

**Question:** How do I ensure the contents in `Dconf Editor` are refreshed such that the removed extensions xxxxx do not appear?

Comment: All the xxxxx schemas that were available to Dconf Editor before I did the above steps. After these steps, their name still appeared. I tried restarting the system but they still appeared in Dconf Editor.

Comment: @PRATAP I see... 3 out of the 8 deleted extensions remained after restarting system. I could not find the `.gschema.xml` file of these 3 extensions in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`.

Comment: @PRATAP Sure. They are arc-menu, blyr, and dynamic-panel-transparency.

Comment: @PRATAP user-theme too; I don't see it in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` but it's folder is still in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` but I had removed it from `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not remove the files manually for unwanted gnome-shell-extensions..
you should remove it from Ubuntu Software or via command line

for example.. some extensions via Ubuntu Software.. some via command line..

even after removing via Ubuntu Software or Via Command Line.. if the schema is still showing on the dconf-editor.. you should manually click the key and earse the particual key/keys

[image]

[image]

Comment: I reinstalled the extensions and used Gnome Software Center to remove the extensions. I found that the "Remove" button deleted the extension's folder in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. But their `.gschema.xml` file that you had earlier told me to copy as sudo to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` weren't deleted. This meant that the removed extensions still appeared in the Dconf Editor. I had to manually 'sudo rm' those schemas, recompile `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`, and open Dconf Editor to press the "Erase Key" to finally remove  the deleted extensions from Dconf Editor.

Comment: yes.. in my previous answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1171112/739431 .. I wrote the way to delete them because the way we copied and compiled to be reverted manually in the same way.. but for those which does not have schema problems.. does not require manual deletion of .gschema.xml files..

Comment: Is pressing the "Remove" button in a GNOME shell extension found in Gnome Software Center suppose to delete it's `.gschema.xml` file in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`? Presently this is not happening. I think it should not happen either as it is owned by sudo. But if this outcome is correct, it will mean that the Dconf Editor would still be plagued by schemas of removed GNOME shell extensions, which is wrong. So what is the correct way to remove an extension so that we can avoid all these complication?

Comment: not all extensions will be installed in `/usr/...` or it may depend whether sudoer is installing or normal user.. lot of extensios are installed in `~/. local/share/gnome-shell/..`

Comment: Do you mean that for extensions that are installed in `~/. local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, there is no need to copy their `.gschema.xml` file in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`? If not, how do these extensions appear in the Dconf Editor? Do I instead have to copy the `.gschema.xml` file of these extensions  to `~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas` and then run `glib-compile-schemas ~/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` in the user terminal?